# Disable unique backgrounds on virtual desktops in Windows 11?

Tags: windows-registry, windows-11, virtual-desktop, background

I use virtual desktops and the Bing Wallpaper app to get a fresh wallpaper every day. It worked great on Windows 10, but with Windows 11 each desktop can have its own unique wallpaper. Now when Bing Wallpaper updates my background, it only does it for the currently active desktop, and switching to other desktops causes my whole computer to freeze while it switches back to the old wallpaper.

Is there some way, a registry tweak or something, that will disable the unique-backgrounds-per-desktop feature? I just want it to update all of them at once, I don't need unique backgrounds for each virtual desktop.

Comment: There does not appear to be a native fix:  .......  https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-bing/bing-wallpaper-app-issue-on-win-11-with-multiple-desktops/m-p/2969683

Comment: Interesting, thanks for that! Glad it's not just me having this issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I use virtual desktops and the Bing Wallpaper app to get a fresh
> wallpaper every day. It worked great on Windows 10, but with Windows
> 11 each desktop can have its own unique wallpaper. Now when Bing
> Wallpaper updates my background, it only does it for the currently
> active desktop, and switching to other desktops causes my whole
> computer to freeze while it switches back to the old wallpaper.

I have a couple of Windows 11 machines here, and researched the issue above.

There is apparently no native fix in Windows 11 for this issue. At least not at this point in time (early 2022), although there may (or may not) be a fix at a later point in time.

[Bing Wallpaper issue](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-bing/bing-wallpaper-app-issue-on-win-11-with-multiple-desktops/m-p/2969683)

Example:

> Having the same issue since switching to win11 a month ago. Only one
> of the desktop is updated daily. They have not yet fixed it.
>
> You have to turn off and then on "daily refresh" to update the
> wallpaper, and then Bing Wallpaper starts to update on the last
> desktop you have done so but stops updating on the others.